# Loading a component with "Scroll to bottom" shows 1 frame when scrollbar is on top and then goes down

Tags: javascript, reactjs, scroll

I'm trying to load a component that is scrollable with the scrollbar at the bottom in the beginning. But in 1 frame, you can see that component is loaded with scrollbar on top and then it goes down. I just want to have the scrollbar at the bottom without delay, because is annoying for user experience

**HTML:**

```
<div ref={chatScrollRef} className={styles.contentWrapper}>
  <div className={styles.contentWrapper__content}/>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.contentWrapper {
  flex: 1;
  position: relative;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
    
  &__content {
    width: 100%;
    height: 1000%;
    position: absolute;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom right, red, yellow);
  }
}
```

**JAVASCRIPT:**

```
useEffect(() => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    chatScrollRef.current.scrollTo({ top: chatScrollRef.current.scrollHeight });
    // chatScrollRef.current.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth' })
  }, 0)
}, [])
```

** "scrollTo" is wrapped inside a setTimeOut to run it after the shortest possible delay. Still it doesn't work

[Problem view](https://gfycat.com/alienatedaccuratearuanas)

** Note that div has a gradient from top to bottom, red to yellow, to see at second 0 how div is red and then it turns to yellow.

Answer (score 0):

There are two solutions to your problem:

1. You can use `flex-direction: column-reverse;` which makes all child items in div reverse and scroll will auto-start "at the end" of the div.
2. Or you can research `react-infinite-scroller` library, which supports infinitely load content and reverse list.